# Как отловить событие перехода на сайт

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

События `$stateChangeStart` или `$locationChangeSuccess` срабатывают при переходе между страницами сайта. А мне бы хотелось отловить событие, когда пользователь первый раз заходит на сайт и узнать URL. Т.е. если пользователь вводит в адресную строку `http://site.ru/user/info`, а доступа у него нет к этой директории, то нужно его перенаправить на логин страницу.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока не задал вопрос не додумался ))).
Код TypeScript Angular 2:

```
constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService) {
    console.log($location.url()); // /user/info
}
```